# Cyclotomic polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}/(p)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, cyclotomic-polynomials

Let $p$ be prime, $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $p \nmid n$.

$\Phi_n$  is the $n$-th cyclotomic polynomial.

How can I find the maximum $n \in \mathbb{N}$ (with $p \nmid n)$ so that $\Phi_n$ splits into linear factors over $\mathbb{Z}/(p)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A root of $\Phi_n$ is an element $a$ such that $a^n=1$ but $a^d\ne 1$ for all $d\mid n$, $d<n$. This suggests $n=p-1$.

Comment: For the sake of completeness: one should check that the claim you write about the roots is still true mod $p$, provided that $p\nmid n$; and this follows if we can prove that the roots of $\Phi_n$ are all distinct in $\overline{\mathbf F_p}$. In fact, the roots of $X^n-1$ are all distinct in $\overline{\mathbf F_p}$, because $X^n-1$ is relatively prime to its derivative $nX^{n-1} \neq 0$ (this is where we must use $p\nmid n$). Since $\Phi_n \mid X^n-1$, the same is true for $\Phi_n$.

Comment: And how can I find other/all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ (with $p \nmid n)$ so that $\Phi_n$ splits into linear factors over $\mathbb{Z}/(p)$? Is this possible?

Comment: All such $n$ are the divisors of $p-1$. You can show this using the same strategy as in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

A heavy artillery answer: for $p\nmid n$, $\Phi_n$ splits completely over $\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z$ if and only if $(p)$ splits completely in $\mathbf Q(\zeta_n)$, if and only if the Frobenius at $p$ is trivial, if and only if $p\equiv 1 \pmod{n}$. The maximal such $n$ is therefore $p-1$.

Comment: Downvoter: I am challenging you to a duel by tic-tac-toe. Let us settle this like men.